# Tensorflow A3C implementation with shared statistics optimizer

Tags: asynchronous, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

Is there opensource `Tensorflow`-based implementation of A3C reinforcement learning algorithm that utilizes optimizer with shared statistics, as in original paper?

*I'm aware of `PyTorch` and `Chainer` versions of A3C with shared RMSProp stats. but failed to find TF one.

The `Shared RMSProp` setup i'm asking about is described in Supp.7 of original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783.pdf):

"...In order to apply RMSProp in the asynchronous optimization
setting one must decide whether the moving average of elementwise squared gradients g is shared or
per-thread. We experimented with two versions of the algorithm. In one version, which we refer to as RMSProp,
each thread maintains its own g...

...In the other version, which we call Shared
RMSProp, the vector g is shared among threads and is updated asynchronously and without locking. Sharing
statistics among threads also reduces memory requirements ...

...RMSProp with shared statistics tends to be more robust than
RMSProp with per-thread statistics, which is in turn more robust than Momentum SGD."

Answer (score 0):

Miyosuda's A3C implementation (found at https://github.com/miyosuda/async_deep_reinforce) utilizes shared RMSProp stats over the training threads.

Further reference at https://github.com/miyosuda/async_deep_reinforce/issues/21

Comment: Thanks! I've overlooked that repository.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an implementation
https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent

The main training loop is in worker.py [here](https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent/blob/f16f37d9d3bc8146cf68a75557e1ba89824b7e54/worker.py#L81) and the observations are produced in separate threads [here](https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent/blob/f16f37d9d3bc8146cf68a75557e1ba89824b7e54/a3c.py#L102)

Comment: Yaroslav, thank you for mentioning this implementation, but it exactly doesn't has the feature a'm talking about. It uses Adam optimizer with per-worker gradients computation. I'll edit my question to be more specific.